# Rails 5.2: secure form_for to prevent user to alter form select_tag / hidden_field values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In my form I'm using `authenticity_token: true` and I'm wondering if this is enough to prevent `current_user` to alter given options for my `select_tag`? Same question applies for using `hidden_field` in my form.

In my case there is a form, where `current_user` can create User and add it to Company. `current_user` can select its own companies, e.g., `current_user.companies.order(:name)`, however I'm worried `current_user` could brake my form and pass in ID of Company, which doesn't belongs to him. Basically in that way `current_user` can become User of foreign Company and then do nasty things...

So far I've been reading https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html and maybe have not noticed some important info there. I'd be happy to know more any security measures I can take to make my form more secure. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this kind of problem arises when you want to validate the record before associating.

The classic solution is to validate them on the server side after submission of the form.

For example, if you only want to create an associated object with user and you are passing `user_id` as `hidden_field`. It is better to create the object directly against current user hence avoiding any manipulation of hidden fields.

Instead of

```
Article.create(article_params) # which includes user_id provided as hidden field

current_user.articles.create(article_params) # no need of user_id
```

So, In your case before creating the new user, you can check something like this

```
user = User.new(params) # remove company_id from here
user.company = current_user.companies.find_by(id: params[:user_params][:company_id]) # This will set company to `nil` if the company is not associated with current user
user.save
```